# Angular Js Callback Function For $timeout

Tags: javascript, callback, angularjs

I have that line of codes

```
...
$timeout(tempFunc, $scope.sync.getDelay());
...
```

at my temp function I have that line of code at end:

```
$scope.sync.releasePrivilege();
```

and everything works well. However when I try:

```
...
$timeout(tempFunc, $scope.sync.getDelay());
$scope.sync.releasePrivilege();
...
```

It doesn't. I think that I should write that line as a callback function into timeout. I don't want to change recent functions at my code I can just edit that lines.

Any ideas?

**PS:** The problem is that:

> $scope.sync.releasePrivilege();

is not running after timeout, it immediately runs.

Comment: What exact "doesn't work"? Can you post not working code to plnkr.co or jsfiddle to see what is wrong

Comment: Can you post plunker example that shows that is not been called after timeout?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$timeout` is a wrapper for `setTimeout` that gets mocked out during testing. @MarkRajcok is completely right about about why using it as a blocking method doesn't work. Mark's solution would also solve your issue. But if it's not feasible to relocate your code, there is still good news!

`$timeout` returns a promise (see [`$q`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)), so you can actually just chain together what you want:

```js
$timeout( tempFunc, $scope.sync.getDelay() ).then( function() {
  console.log("I'm called only after the timeout.");
  $scope.sync.releasePrivilege();
});

console.log("But I get called immediately.");
```

And this should work just fine, should you fancy. It still doesn't block. It just ensures that the function within the `then` call is executed *only after the promise is resolved*, that is only when the timeout has completed and your method has been called.

Additionally, your function can return data, if needed. So if `tempFunc` returned a Boolean value that indicated success, you could also access it:

```js
$timeout( tempFunc, $scope.sync.getDelay() ).then( function( result ) {
  if ( result ) {
    $scope.sync.releasePrivilege();
  } else {
    // handle the error
  }
});
```

And there was much rejoicing. Yay.

---

Just as a note: doing a sleep in a browser would be very bad - it'd lock the UI. Asynchronous execution is what makes the web an awesome platform!

Answer (score 1):

Timeout does not provide the equivalent of a "sleep".  $timeout puts work (in your case, tempFunc) on the native event queue, and hence tempFunc will be called later (after the browser renders).  `$scope.sync.releasePrivilege();` will therefore be executed before tempFunc.  As you stated, if you want releasePrivilege() to execute after tempFunc(), have tempFunc() call it.

Comment: I think you got the idea about what I ask. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: I don't think so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: should I use setTimeout or $timeout does the same?

Comment: @kamaci `$timeout` is a wrapper for `setTimeout` that gets mocked out during testing, so definitely use it instead. Doing a sleep in a browser would be very bad - it'd lock the UI. Asynchronous execution is what makes the web an awesome platform. But `$timeout` returns a promise, so just chain it: `$timeout(...).then(function(){ $scope.sync.releasePrivilege() });`.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller you should write that as an answer, it works.